# Space Reserved for Scrollbar Cutting off Text

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm facing a strange issue where the table header gets cut off(represented by the yellow part which is about 20px) and hence also the text:

[image]

As per my investigation this is because this is sort of reserving some space for a vertical scrollbar(although it never shows up in the header section). This becomes apparent when the table data is large enough to introduce a scrollbar(which also occupies a width of about 20px) or when I zoom into the page but like I said, the scrollbar appears only in the data section:
[image]

I'm using Razor Syntax(Custom Helper Methods) to create the table and can't find any issue in my code for this particular screen from where this problem might be arising.

FYI this issue persists across multiple browsers(I've tried Chrome, Edge & IE)

I've done a temporary fix where in I've introduced a div within the last header column and kept some space between them so that it is the empty space which gets trimmed off and not the text. But this is not a permanent solution.

Can someone please guide?

Answer (score 0):

You can give your table the css property "overflow-x: scroll;" so that you can scroll to see it instead of it being cut off. You can also set the padding to have less space between everything inside of the boxes in the table. You can set the width and max-width property of the table as well. I hope this helps.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <title> Try It Yourself </title>
   <style type="text/css">
      table {
         table-layout: fixed;
         width: 110%;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         font-family: sans-serif;
         overflow-x: scroll;
      }
      table, th, td {
         border: 1px solid black;
      }
      th, td {
         padding: 0px;
         text-align: center;
      }
      /* selects the first th element */
      thead th:nth-child(1) {
         width: 30%;
      }
      /* selects the second th element */
      thead th:nth-child(2) {
         width: 30%;
      }
      /* selects the third th element */
      thead th:nth-child(3) {
         width: 40%;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th> Heading </th>
            <th> Heading </th>
            <th> Heading </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td> The overflow  will be seen by scrolling</td>
            <td> The overflow  will be seen by scrolling</td>
            <td> The overflow  will be seen by scrolling</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> The overflow  will be seen by scrolling</td>
            <td> The overflow  will be seen by scrolling</td>
            <td> The overflow  will be seen by scrolling</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> The overflow  will be seen by scrolling</td>
            <td> The overflow  will be seen by scrolling</td>
            <td> The overflow  will be seen by scrolling</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```